# app móvil en Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, aplicación-movil

como puedo hacer que la aplicación móvil sea autoajustable al la pantalla del celular por ejemplo un Android 10 ya que se programo para un celular grande android 13 pero al instalar en un celular pequeño no se ajusta a la pantalla

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.